# Cleaning up phone number entries with ".delete" in Ruby

Tags: ruby, csv, formatting, phone-number, ruby-1.9.3

I'm cleaning up a few phone number entries in a CSV file using Ruby. Some users have entered unwanted characters and I want to sort through and delete them all (some include: periods, parenthesis, hyphens). While writing my code, I realized I could use the .delete method provided by Ruby, like so:

```
  def clean_num
   @file.each do |line|
    number = line[3]
    #Would need a .delete for every unwanted character?
    clean_number = number.delete(".")
    puts clean_number
   end
  end
```

What's a more efficient way to delete the other characters mentioned above?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're looking for regular expressions:

```
clean_number = number.gsub(/[^\d]/, "")
```

The first argument to `gsub` is the pattern to find, the second is what to replace each occurrance with.

This replaces everything that isn't a digit (`[^\d]`) with an empty string (`""`).

Comment: Is there not a more efficient way to do a .delete asides from listing out the method x amount of times? Thanks for the gsub code!

Comment: You *could*, but why? That doesn't accurately describe your intent: You're not trying to delete a certain set of characters, you're trying to delete everything that isn't a digit, so just *do that*. Delete non-digits. This is easier, cleaner, faster and more expressive.

Comment: That said, yes, to delete a series of characters I would either still use a regular expression (`number.gsub(/[-(),.]/, ""`) or, if you're really seriously hung up on using `delete` specifically, use a loop: `"-(),.".each_char { |c| number = number.delete(c) }`

Comment: Ah yes, it's real clear when you laid it out in that manner. Regex is most definitely more expressive and clean. Thanks meagar, appreciate it!

Comment: use `gsub(/\D/, "")` instead of `gsub(/[^\d]/, "")`. Using `/[^d]/` is the long way around: `'1 (555) 555-1212'.gsub(/\D/, '')
 => "15555551212"`

Comment: Learning regex for the first time; really appreciate the feedback Tin!